# Precision and Recall of a combined classifier

Tags: precision-recall

I have two classifiers, trained on the same dataset, each predicting a different variable. let's call these X1 and X2. They have their respective precision and recall measures X1-p,r, and X2-p,r.

I now have consumers asking for a "composite prediction" `Y = f(X1, X2)`. Say `f` is as simple as `X1 = 'x1' OR X2 = 'x2'`.

**Question** - Am I able to provide precision and recall for `Y` using those for `X1, X2`?

My sense is not, since I need the *joint probabilities* for `X1, X2` to answer this?

Comment: Precision and recall of *what*?

Comment: Precision and recall of ```Y``` in my example above?

Comment: $Y$ is not binary, so it is not clear what precision and recall wild mean. I can think of some definitions that strike me as reasonable generalizations if the usual definitions, but that’s me. How do you define the terms?